# what goes inside dialog constructor

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-dialog

i know it should be context.
what exactly is a context though.
usually when i create a dialog in a class 
i do something like this:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
```

but now i am trying to create a dialog in an AsyncTask<>
therefore i cannot do the above cause AsyncTask isn't a context evidently.
the AsyncTask is a class in itself, which is to say its not a subclass right now.

```
public class popTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

Context con =

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(con);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
    dialog.setTitle("New & Hot advertise");

    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
    ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.yoda);

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are the two ways you can send your context from the activity where you are executing your AsyncTask:

```
popTask pTask = new popTask(mContext); //OR
pTask.execute(mContext);
```

In your `popTask` create a private variable where you can set your context.

In the first option you need to have a constructor for your class `popTask` where you are accepting a context.

For the second option if you are not passing anything meaningful to the function `doInBackground()` you can change the following line:

```
public class popTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>

protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
this.mContext = (Context) params[0];
```

}

you will receive the context object in the `doInBackground()` which you can set in the private Context variable of the `popTask` class and then access it in the `doInBackground()` function.

Comment: after creating the first option.

Comment: i can execute by doing pTask.execute();

Comment: Yes I have included a OR which mean either of the two solution but not both at once. If you are using the first option then you can use `pTask.execute()`. Hope the answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Samir's Answer

Modify your code to have constructor which take context of calling class.

```
public class popTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private Context context;
    public popTask(Context context)
    {
        this.cotext=context;
    }
```

and then `Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);`

In your calling activity call this Asynctask like this

`new popTask(ActivityName.this).execute();`

Comment: does seem to accept ActivityName.class but instead ActivityName.this. not sure about the diff.. just letting u know. thanks again for the help

Comment: oh sorry...it should be ActivityName.this..I updated my answer.Also accept the answer so it will be helpful for others who are having similar issue.

Comment: now there arent any compilation errors but the dialog just wont show up... perhaps i need to use runOnUiThread() somewhere?